# type conversion to integer in ruby

Tags: ruby, type-conversion

I am using latest ruby version[ruby 2.4.1p111]

I am getting the result of `'123'.to_i +12` to 171

```
irb(main):021:0> '123'.to_i + 12
=> 135
irb(main):022:0> '123'.to_i +12
=> 171
irb(main):023:0> 123 + 12
=> 135
irb(main):024:0> 123 +12
=> 135
```

Can you help me understand the second operation here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ended up calling the [unary plus](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Numeric.html#method-i-2B-40) operator in the second example, which

> Returns the receiver’s value

and then you ended up with (essentially):

```
'123'.to_i 12
```

and since, [`to_i`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-to_i) takes an argument, `base`, you ended up converting `'123'` to an integer in base 12, which is, apparently, 171.

Answer (score 2):

`to_i` can take an argument, the base, and its default is 10.

What you did is:

```
'123'.to_i(12)
```

[String#to_i](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-to_i)